# Highlight an ion-item dynamically created by ng-repeat, on clicking the ion-item

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have to highlight an ion-item dynamically created by ng-repeat when the ion-item is clicked. I have tried assigning each item an id and then passing the id to the ng-click function which is expected to highlight the color according to the requirement.Yet the color doesn't change.Am I missing something?.

Here is the html code -

```
`<ion-item id="{{WindReports.menuitemid}}" ng-repeat="WindReports in $root.UserWindAccess" menu-close href="{{WindReports.cAction}}" style="border : none !important;" ng-click="setClickedRow(WindReports.menuitemid)">
                            {{WindReports.cMenuName }}
</ion-item>
```

Controller.js -

```
$scope.setClickedRow = function (index) {
        document.getElementById(index).style.backgroundColor = red;
    }
```

Comment: you could use `ng-class` with `someVariable`. and then toggle `someVariable` on click of row. That's it..

Comment: Guess you missed the quotes in your function. `document.getElementById(index).style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Comment: @PankajParkar did that too according to the following link - http://code.ciphertrick.com/2014/12/06/highlight-a-selected-row-in-ng-repeat-using-ng-class/ 

No result.

Comment: @lexith no luck. did that too.

Comment: replace your ion-item with a normal div for testing. i don't know how `ion-item` works nowadays but it probably has a child container which you have to style instead of the directive itself.

Comment: @lexith got it. Yeah the color changed. Thanks